# RubyMine Rails Remote Debug rdebug-ide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, remote-debugging, rubymine, rdebug

I'm using RubeMine to develop RAILS code.
And I'm using remote debugging between RubyMine and rdebug-ide.

All works very well, but there is a minor point the debugger failes.

In RAILS I'm using in the MODEL :

```
has_one_attached :paper
```

When running nativly without the debugger, I can access and ask e.g:

```
object.paper.attached?
```

But the same line of code failes when running in debugger.

**ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `paper'.....**

So my mind goes into the direction the debugger is the reason.
Version Information:

```
rdebug-ide -v
Using ruby-debug-base 0.2.4.1

gem list | grep ruby-debug     
ruby-debug-ide (0.7.2)
```

And idea to fix that ?

Comment: Which RubyMine are you using? In addition, what kind of remote SDK do you have (SSH, Docker, Vagrant)?

Comment: I'm using RubyMine 2021.1.1 and using sshConfig.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you added a remote SDK via Add - New Remote - SSH?

Comment: Hi Olivia, I'm not sure - because I'm using the "Remote Debugging Feature" since years without troubles. Make it sense to delete the Remote Feature and Add/New SSH ?

Comment: I was wondering whether in this case it will work properly (using the first way from the documentation here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/remote-debugging.html)

Comment: yes it works very well - but not when the code hit this object.paper.attached?.

Comment: It's worth submitting an issue on RubyMine's tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY). A project sample if possible would be also helpful